TikZ package error: pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex: You can't use `\unskip' in vertical mode error
I cannot figure out what causes a whole chain of error messages:
204: You can't use `\unskip' in vertical mode. }
at the said line of the document:
pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex
in the LaTeX document example below.
Working through the 'Tikz and PGF Manual' tutorials that accompany my LaTeX installation, I get the same error messages running many of the examples, which fail to compile. This makes me think that I am doing something wrong.  As Editor, I use TexStudio on macOS Sonoma, and LaTeX 2024 installed through HomeBrew.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
    
A couple of boxes, circles, and arrows:

\vspace{1cm}
    
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] (0,1) -- (4,1) -- (4,3) -- (0,3) -- (0,1);
    \draw[thick] (2,1) -- (2,3);
    \filldraw [black] (1,2) circle [radius=5pt]
                      (3,2) circle [radius=5pt];
    \draw[thick] [->] (3,2) -- (5,2) ;
    \draw[thick] [->] (1,2) -- (1,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! tikz libraries had to be loaded in document preamble (before \begin{document}).

Thank you for the kind greeting and the solution! Would you kindly post as answer that I may accept?

Libraries of packages (if they have) had to be loaded in document preamble (before \begin{document}. For example, at tikz package in your case the MWE (Minimal working example) should be:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta} % should be loaded in preamble!

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
    
A couple of boxes, circles, and arrows:

\vspace{1cm}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] (0,1) -- (4,1) -- (4,3) -- (0,3) -- (0,1);
    \draw[thick] (2,1) -- (2,3);
    \filldraw [black] (1,2) circle [radius=5pt]
                      (3,2) circle [radius=5pt];
    \draw[thick,->] (3,2) -- (5,2) ; % write rather such than [thick] [->]
    \draw[thick,->] (1,2) -- (1,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{document}


